# different log files with akka-http

Tags: scala, logging, akka, akka-http

I'm a bit confused about logging in akka in general.

Currently I have a trait called Logger that are included in any Handlers, etc. I want to log:

```
trait Logger { this: ServiceBase =>
  val log = Logging(system, this)
  val auditLog = ???
}
```

What I want to achieve is having this auditLog logger, whose input would be sent to a different file, and would provide an audit log such as this:

```
Info - User X changed his password
Info - User Y created by User X
Warn - 5 consecutive invalid password for user Y, locking user for 30 minutes

etc.
```

Comment: Do I understand you correctly, you want to have logging of sent and received messages logged so you can auto based on an Actor? Or Audit based on specific messages?

Comment: Audit based on specific messages in code. I want to have the normal logging (info, debug, warning etc), sent to stdout, and ultimately picked up by upstart and written to a file, and ALSO another logger which will write specific messages to a different sink (a file on disk in my case)